# Testing if there is an object with a particular attribute in an array of dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, for-in-loop

Ok boys and gils, i've a question for the community.

I actually have an `NSMutableArray` with some `NSDictionnary` in it.

I perform a `-(void) refresh` method to parse my JSON feed a new time, but before adding a News (yes it's for displaying news) onto the `NSMutableArray`i'd like to check if there's not the same news in the Array.

So I thinks that i have to use multiple for, forin and if boucles & conditions, but I don't how.

I try to put the news title into an `NSArray` and then check if in the return of json parsing there's a news with the same article, without any result.

I unfortunatelly erase the code and save the project so I apologize, i've no code to show you.

Thanks.

Comment: What can we found in the NSDictionary? The news information? And what must we check? id, title or something else?

Comment: You wrote "[...] but before adding a News (yes it's for displaying news) onto the NSMutableArray [...]."  What sort of entity is "a News"?

Comment: the property is `title`, `content`, `datepub`, `publisher` i can access to an `id` too (all NSStrings)

Comment: @NateChandler news is an object, inherited from NSObject (see proprety on last comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way... first append the array whatever news are coming from Json or any source,
Then do this logic.

```
NSArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"A",@"C",@"A", nil];    
NSMutableArray *arr=[NSMutableArray new];
for(id obj in array){
    if (![arr containsObject:obj]) {
        [arr addObject:obj];
    }
}
array=arr;
NSLog(@"==> %@",array);
```

Also you can do in this way:

```
NSArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"A",@"C",@"A", nil];    
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:array forKeys:array];
array=[dict allKeys];

NSLog(@"==> %@",array);
```

Output :

```
==> (
    A,
    B,
    C
)
```

Comment: I'll try this tonight and upvote if it's work
EDIT : In fact, due to lack of time I perform a 
`myArray removeAllObject` and then add the object and then a `[[sel tableView]reloadData]` i'm in the train, i'll test it on device a home

Comment: OK, you may need to change few things in this code, because this code was for some other requirement but very similar to yours one.